# Failed to upgrade Bot Framework Sample to latest nuget package versions on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've created a sample bot on Azure, downloaded it and upgraded all nuget packages to  their latest stable versions. (Except for one package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt which Microsoft.Bot.Builder required to be less than 5.0)

Also changed .net framework to 4.7 and the C# compiler to the latest minor version.

Due to alleged backward compatibility I assumed this to work. And it does locally. 
Bot emulator works just fine.

However back on Azure it does not. In the settings .net framework 4.7 was selected.

The homepage does not crash and is displayed correctly. However messages are not delivered to the bot.

I assume there is a limitation on Bot Builder SDK versions that azure supports, 
but i did not find any such statement.

The logs show "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" Could not find more specific information.

Did anyone run into similar problem?

And in general, what's the best practice of upgrading your production application's libraries?

Comment: Did you replace the [Messaging endpoint](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-gahz8LAKAhA/WPrPqRmMgTI/AAAAAAAAEdY/5gSjVyymtZUSTSJrjEuYm0WQJPrBjN1fwCEw/s1600/image002.png) with the azure site url?

Comment: I also tested the azure deployed bot on azure portal itself

Comment: Sorry that I cannot help much about it. Maybe search the answered issues on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=azure%20500) or create a new one.